# Swapping "words" in a list of strings in Python

Tags: python, string, list

So, let's say I have a list:

```
excuses=['Please go away, DND', 
         'Didn't you hear me? DND', 
         'I said DND!']
```

and I want to switch "DND" with "do not disturb", is there a quick and easy way to do that?
I've read a little through the list of methods for Python, but I must've overlooked something, I didn't find anything that could help me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`str.replace`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#str.replace) to substitute string:

```
>>> "Please go away, DND".replace('DND', 'do not disturb')
'Please go away, do not disturb'
```

And using [List comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), you get a new list with each item string substituted:

```
>>> excuses = ["Please go away, DND", "Didn't you hear me? DND", "I said DND!"]
>>> [excuse.replace('DND', 'do not disturb') for excuse in excuses]
['Please go away, do not disturb', "Didn't you hear me? do not disturb", 'I said do not disturb!']
```

Comment: I don't know why, but writing it like you did gave me a syntax error. I managed to get around the error with:
    `for i in range(len(excuses)):
        excuses[i].replace('DND','do not disturb')`

But then it doesn't replace, and it just prints the original list.

Comment: @Mark, Try `[excuse.replace('DND', 'do not disturb') for excuse in excuses]` (without leading `>>> `)

Comment: I found what I had done wrong, at `excuse.replace` I had written `excuses.replace`.

Comment: List comprehension does not change the original list. It just return new list.  To change the original list, reassign the list comprehension back to the variable: `excuses = [excuse.replace('DND', 'do not disturb') for excuse in excuses]`